# angular 2 table collapse not working properly while sorting

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on angular 2. I am creating collapsible using `ngFor` directive in html table and sorting the table column wise. Before sorting the child collapse row placed between the main rows and working as expected but after sorting the collapsible rows showing top of the all rows.

Using sort option is only for main row not for inner collapse row.

Couldn't add image for clear explanation.

stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zoytga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
<tbody class="portfolio-tbody">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let liveData of liveDatas let i=index">
        <tr class="portfolio-tr">
            <td class="portfolio-td">{{liveData.siteName}}
                <img src="../../images/caret.svg" class="portfolio-table-caret" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'.' + i" (click)="expandDevice(liveData.siteName, $event)">
            </td>
            <td class="portfolio-td">{{liveData.address}}</td>
            <td class="portfolio-td"><img src="../../images/{{liveData.ledHealth == 1 ? 'on_icon' : 'off_icon'}}.png"></td>
            <td class="portfolio-td"><img src="../../images/{{liveData.lightStatus == 1 ? 'on_icon' : 'off_icon'}}.png"></td>
            <td class="portfolio-td">{{liveData.SV}}</td>
            <td class="portfolio-td">{{liveData.SC}}</td>
            <td class="portfolio-td">{{liveData.BV}}</td>
            <td class="portfolio-td">{{liveData.BC}}</td>
            <td class="portfolio-td">{{liveData.ts | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let thisSitsDevice of thisSitsDevices let ind=index">
            <ng-container *ngIf="liveData.siteName==thisSitsDevice.siteName">
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/energy-index']">
                        <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>{{thisSitsDevice.deviceName}}</div>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>{{thisSitsDevice.address}}</div>
                </td>
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>
                        <img src="../../images/{{thisSitsDevice.ledHealth == 1 ? 'on_icon' : 'off_icon'}}.png">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>
                        <img src="../../images/{{thisSitsDevice.lightStatus == 1 ? 'on_icon' : 'off_icon'}}.png">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>{{thisSitsDevice.SV}}</div>
                </td>
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>{{thisSitsDevice.SC}}</div>
                </td>
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>{{thisSitsDevice.BV}}</div>
                </td>
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>{{thisSitsDevice.BC}}</div>
                </td>
                <td class="hiddenRow portfolio-td-devices">
                    <div class="collapse panel-collapse in" class={{i}}>{{thisSitsDevice.ts | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>

    </ng-container>
    <tr *ngIf=" !liveDatas || liveDatas.length == 0 ">
        <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="9">No data to display....</td>
    </tr>
    <!--  <tr *ngIf=" liveDatas == undefined">
                <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="9">Loading....</td>
            </tr> -->
</tbody>
```

> Sorting query:

```
sortTable(f: any, n: number, sortingOrder: string) {
    var rows = $('#portfolio-table tbody .portfolio-[tr][1]').get();

    rows.sort(function(a: any, b: any) {

        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);

        if (sortingOrder == 'descending') {
            if (A < B) {
                return -1 * f;
            }
        }

        if (sortingOrder == 'ascending') {
            if (A > B) {
                return 1 * f;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });

    function getVal(elm: any) {
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
        if ($.isNumeric(v)) {
            v = parseInt(v, 10);
        }
        return v;
    }

    $.each(rows, function(index: any, row: any) {
        $('#portfolio-table').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}
sorting(sortingOrder: string) {
    this.f_sl *= -1;
    var n = 1
    this.sortTable(this.f_sl, n, sortingOrder);
}
```

And sorting also not working properly.

Comment: can you please create a https://stackblitz.com/ example of your problem?

Comment: @Sudhan, you forget a ";" in the *ngFor let thisSitsDevice of thisSitsDevices **;** let ind=index. FutherMore, use your liveDatas variable to sort (FORGET some so "bizarro" like var rows = $('#portfolio-table tbody .portfolio-[tr][1]').get();
)

Comment: @ForestG  i am new to this stackblitz i am not able map jquey library. please find exapmle editor        https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zoytga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your problem is that you're still "thinking in jQuery".

You don't want to manipulate directly the dom, in Angular.

You want to manipulate *the data* that builds the Dom, so whenever you change it, Angular can do his magic.

In your code you read the dom and sort it, instead of simply working on your data.

First: use TypeScript at your advantage. `liveDatas` is not an `any`, at least can be a `any[]`. You could also define a typing for your record class, and get autocompletion for your liveDatas records.

Second: just sort your data, not the rows:

```
sortTable(f: number, n: number, sortingOrder: string) {
  this.liveDatas.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a.siteName > b.siteName) return f;
    if (a.siteName < b.siteName) return -f;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Third: allow Angular's ngFor to track your rows when sorting them, so the Dom elements are actually swapped, instead of destroyed. Probably it will not make a huge difference, but sometimes it will, and it's a good habit:

```
<!-- in your .html -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let liveData of liveDatas; let i=index; trackBy: trackByUniqueId">
```

And the body of the track by function

```
// in your .ts
trackByUniqueId(index: number, value: any): any {
  return value.siteName + value.ts; 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If it’s working fine you should upvote and mark the question as answered ;)